# Differentiability of a defined corner of a function?

Tags: calculus, continuity

This is my first question so I apologise in advance if it doesn't fit the format that is expected, and I would appreciate any advice on how to ask questions properly.

I am given a function;

[g(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcd71.png)

I am then asked to do the following:

[Question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahYhW.png)

The problem is that it really doesn't seem to me to be differentiable at $0$. $g(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$. Using the Squeezing Theorem I determined that the limit of $g(x)$ exists at $0$. The function $g(x)$ is even, and is therefore symmetric across the y axis. This implies that as both sides of the function approach $(0,0)$ they both make the same angle with the x axis. $h(x)$ fills the discontinuity, but surely that could not make it differentiable just because it is continuous? The opposite sides of the y-axis must meet at a corner, and corners cannot have tangents, right? Also, I'm a first year undergraduate, so an appropriately complex answer would be very much appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you've looked at various heuristics that are often useful, and calculated some things that you could, what you've forgotten to try is to go back to the very basics.

Recall that the very definition of "differentiable" is:

> $h$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if the following limit exists:
>   $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x} $$

which is a straightforward calculation after substituting in the definition of $h$.

---

A point you overlooked in your heuristic reasoning is that when you said:

> This implies that as both sides of the function approach $(0,0)$ they both make the same angle with the x axis.

you overlooked *what* angle they make: in fact, the angle turns out to be zero.